# Embedded base64 image to <input> not shown

Tags: html, css, image

I have two input on my page with background-images.
But i can't see this images for some reasons..
[image]

```
<div id="tocNavBtnsBar">
      <input type="image" id="tocShowBtn" onclick="showTOC(true)">
      <input type="image" id="tocHideBtn" onclick="showTOC(false)">
</div>
```

Also CSS:

```
#tocHideBtn {
position: absolute;
top: 52%;
height: 5mm;
width: 5mm;
background-color: #787474;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

If i select url in DevTools, than i can see image...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the HTML Input element incorrectly.

You did not specify an image source for the input element. Unlike other elements, like `DIV` or `input[type=text]` you cannot specify a background image the way that you have.

---

1. The solution is to remove the following from your CSS code: `background-image: url(...)`
2. Then you will want to extract the Base64 encoded image out from `url(...)`.
3. Finally, copy the base 64 URL to the `src` attribute of the image element.

---

This solution is similar to using an `<img src="..." />` element (with the `src` attribute).

---

Check out these results:

```html
<div>
      <input type="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:black">
</div>
```